# How Do I Do This Integral?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, integration, coherent-states

I am trying to derive a boson coherent path integral and one part of the derivation is to evaluate/prove

$$
\int d\Psi(\tau) d\Psi^*(\tau) |\Psi(\tau)|^{2n} \exp(-|\Psi(\tau)|^2) = (n!) \pi.
$$

This is what I tried to do

$$
\int d\Psi(\tau) d\Psi^*(\tau) (\Psi)^n(\Psi^*)^n \exp(-\Psi(\tau) \Psi(\tau)^*) = \int d \Psi(\tau) \Psi^n\int(\Psi^*)^n \exp(-\Psi \Psi^*) d\Psi^* =  \int d \Psi(\tau) \Psi^n\bigg[ n! (1/\Psi)^{n+1}\bigg]
$$

I was using $\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x/a} dx = n! a^{n+1}$

**How do I derive this integral?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a substitution $\Psi=\rho\exp(i\phi)$, $\Psi^*=\rho\exp(-i\phi)$, the absolute value of the Jacobian of the transformation is $2\pi\rho$. Integration over $\phi$ is trivial; to calculate the integral over $\rho$ use integration by parts and induction.

Comment: Thank you very much !!